# Как правильно организовать структуру простого чата в бд

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно это делается.

Есть 2 пользователя, которые могу обмениваться сообщениями и удалять сообщения из видимости на своей странице.

У меня такая структура:

```
id user to_user message date
```

но еще нужно, чтоб пользователь мог удалить из чата сообщения, но сущность сообщения самого осталась.

Я думаю это сделать 2 полями с булевыми значениями, что повлечет за собой лишние запросы. Т. к. по сути сущности диалога нет, есть только сообщения, которые связываются и образуют диалог, а значит есть 2 варианта: `user to_user` и `to_user user`.

** нужно чтоб пользователь могу удалить сообщение , тем самым сообение становится не видимым для данного пользователя. но оно видно для его собеседниика.

В общем, чтоб не городить городушки обращаюсь к вам за советом)

Спасибо.

Comment: Я бы в `mysql` лучше не помещал таблицу с сообщениями чата, т.к. это слишком жирно станет для нее при выборке. Либо поиграйся с типами таблиц и масштабированием. Для реализации мягкого удаления сделай поле `is_removed`, большинство фреймворков содержат уже готовые поведения для работы с мягким удалением.

Comment: я немного не понимаю очем конкретно вы говорите. если честно:(

Comment: _нужно, чтоб пользователь мог удалить из чата сообщения_ Вообще для всех или только для себя? в первом случае можно обойтись без доп. полей, достаточно изменить знак `user_id`.

Comment: Изменять знак user_id - за гранью добра и зла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Базовая комплектация чата на любое количество персон:

```
Conversations (id)
Participants (conv_id, user_id)
Messages (id, conv_id, user_id, message)
```

Если ограничение количества беседующих до двух железно, убрать таблицу `Participants`, добавить поля `user_1`, `user_2` в `Conversations`. Однако в запросе появятся страшные конструкции вида:

```
(c.user1=:a AND c.user2=:b OR c.user2=:a AND c.user1=:b)
```

Возможно, имеет смысл не запрещать существование конференций на уровне базы, просто не создавать их (*пока, однажды вы заходите кнопочку "Добавить собеседника"*)

#### Возможность одностороннего удаления сообщений

Для этого нужно хранить где-то лог неудалённых сообщений каждого юзера:

```
UserMessages (user_id, message_id)
```

Из которой мы и будем удалять строчки.